# How to prevent users from browsing certain files of my website

Tags: web

I have recently launched a website on GoDaddy hosting. I have keept some images and JavaScript files used in website, in separate folders. I want to prevent the users from browsing those images and files by simply appending the folder and file name in the website URL. For example
www.example.com/images/logo.png

Comment: Write more details about hosting and also try to clarify what exactly you want to achieve. It's pretty hard to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have html file with images, that shouldn't be accessible alone? If yes, then it cannot be done. You can watch for correct HTTP Referrer header, but it can be simply faked and it also makes it inaccessible for browsers that don't send referrer or having sending it forbidden for "privacy" reasons.

If you want hide files to be accessible only by server side scripts, ftp/scp, then you can try to use .htaccess (if GoDaddy runs on Apache) and correct configuration: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Another way could be hiding that files and creating one-shot token like this:
`<img src=<?pseudocode GEN_TOKEN("file.jpg") ?> />` with another file serving these hidden files just for generated token, then deleting it from DB. Nevertheless, this will not protect anybody from downloading or accessing these files, if they want...

But, anyway, try to clarify your question better...

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping images/files in folder which is open to public, I guess you kept in that folder for purpose, you want public to access those images and files.

How public know images file name? Stop file content listing for your web site.

I am not aware which language you are using on web server, but in ASP.NET you may write module/ middle ware which can intercept in coming request and based on your logic (e.g. authentication and authorization)  you can restrict access. All modern languages support this kind of functionality.